# window.open() não funcionando corretamente no Firefox e Chrome

Tags: javascript

Estou usando o seguinte JavaScript para ocultar a barra de endereço em popup:

```
oncomplete="window.open('lista_persist.xhtml', 'newwindow', 'directories=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,location=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1, width=800, height=600');"
```

Porém a barra de endereço somente é ocultada no IE, tentei dessa maneira também:

```
oncomplete="window.open('lista_persist.xhtml', 'newwindow', 'directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes, width=800, height=600');"
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar, desde já agradeço !

Comment: Isso não é mais possível nos navegadores modernos devido a restrições de segurança, como aponta essa outra resposta: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603308/hiding-address-bar-in-all-browsers , mas se quiser esconder a barra de navegação no android, pode fazer isso: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068559/removing-address-bar-from-browser-to-view-on-android

Comment: Muito obrigado !

Comment: @AndersonMadeira crie uma resposta sobre isso.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Medidas de segurança e anti phishing forçaram os navegadores modernos a não mais permitir que a barra de endereço seja escondida. É bom lembrar que as informações dos certificados SSL, que desempenham um papel crucial na segurança de um site na web, aparecem na barra de endereço, então é necessário ter ela lá, como uma medida anti phishing e pra verificar a autenticidade do site.

Docs oficiais do navegadores deixam isso mais claro:

Na doc do firefox, ele diz que a presença da barra de endereço é forçada:

- [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open#Toolbar_and_chrome_features):

> In Firefox 3, dom.disable_window_open_feature.location now defaults to true, forcing the presence of the Location Bar much like in IE7. See bug 337344 for more information.

Em relação ao Internet Explorer, a doc diz que isso acabou com a versão 6:

- [+IE7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> In Internet Explorer 6, location specifies whether to display the Address Bar.

E a mais enfática, diz que esses parâmetros são ignorados:

- [Chrome/Chromium](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=81506):

> Those toolbar hiding parameters are ignored in Chrome. You will also notice that modern browsers are moving towards not hiding it as security / anti phishing measures. Also see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=337344

Comment: Muito obrigado !